# Webservice parameter value encoding

Tags: .net, web-services, encoding

We have a webservice created in WCF and presenting itself as a basicHttpBinding. One of the parameters is a string which takes an xml string. Looking at the soap the client generates to send to the webservice, the xml is encoded, with all < and > swapped into &lt; and &gt;. My question is, is this all that is encoded, or has the parameter been run through HtmlEncode so that other entities would be swapped also?

The reason I ask is we are submitting with our client to a 3rd party webservice now and they would like to know the details on what is encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not HMTMEncoded**.

But to make it a valid string in XML the following characters must be escaped:

```
 &  =>  &amp;amp; 
 <   =>  &amp;lt;
 >   =>  &amp;gt; 
 "  =>  &amp;quot;
 '  =>  &amp;apos;
```

", ' and & **must** not neccessarily be escaped (however they should be), as their meaning depends on their use inside the xml string.

See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) for the exact rules.

Comment: from the sample I have its definately < and > however " seems to have been untouched

Comment: That's what I meant by the statement that ", ' and & no not necessarily have to be replaced to get wellformed CData. However, normally & needs to be escaped to &amp; when entity references are used, i.e &amp; should become &amp;amp;. Much like the edit I did for you in the OP ... :-)